# Angular app is compiling successfully but giving errors property does not exist in 'ng build --prod'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build

Angular app is compiling successfully but giving the following errors in 'ng build --prod'

```
ERROR in src\app\header\header.component.html(31,124): : Property 'searchText' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
src\app\dashboard\dashboard.component.html(3,72): : Property 'newsService' is private and only accessible within class 'DashboardComponent'.
src\app\dashboard\dashboard.component.html(3,72): : Property 'p' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'.
src\app\dashboard\dashboard.component.html(29,46): : Property 'p' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'.
```

I have used these properties in my html file as below:
`header.component.html`file

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mr-2 align-self-center" required placeholder="Search" name="searchText" [ngModel]="searchText" value="">
```

`dashboard.component.html`file

```
<pagination-controls class="text-center" (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

my `header.component.html` file

```
import { Component,  OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  filterText : string;
@Output() search = new EventEmitter();
@Output() filterButton = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit(form : NgForm)
  {
    console.log(form);
    this.search.emit(form);
  }

  filterClicked($event)
  {
    this.filterText = $event.target.text;
    this.filterButton.emit(this.filterText);
  }
}
```

my `dashboard.component.html` file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../shared/news.service';
import { NewsModel } from '../shared/news.model';
import { Form } from '@angular/forms';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { element } from 'protractor';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  articles : any;
  temp : NewsModel = new NewsModel;
  constructor(private newsService : NewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.FetchHeadlines();
           }

  FetchHeadlines()
  {
     this.newsService.GetAllGaurdian()
        .subscribe((result) =>
        {
          this.articles = result;
                  this.articles.response.results.forEach(element => {
                       this.newsService.newsArticles.push(this.newsService.CusotomMapper(element));
          });
        }) 
  }
}
```

can't able to figure out where is the error exactly!

Comment: you can use `ng build` without --prod and `npm publish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error descriptions are as accurate as it can be. each of them tells you that something wrong with your component, lets examine each of them

ERROR:

```
ERROR in src\app\header\header.component.html(31,124): : Property 'searchText' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
```

you have **searchText** in `HeaderComponent` HTML, but not in the Component itself

SOLUTION: add searchText variable to the Component

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
      searchText:string
      ...
    }
```

ERROR :

```
src\app\dashboard\dashboard.component.html(3,72): : Property 'newsService' is private and only accessible within class 'DashboardComponent'.
```

all the fields you are using inside the template, must be the public field inside component itself, otherwise it will not compile

SOLUTION: change private modifier to public at newService

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public newsService : NewsService) { }
...
}
```

ERRORS :

```
src\app\dashboard\dashboard.component.html(3,72): : Property 'p' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'.
src\app\dashboard\dashboard.component.html(29,46): : Property 'p' does not exist on type 'DashboardComponent'.
```

same as HeaderComponent. you are using **p** field but it's not defined in DashboardComponent

SOLUTION : add p field to the dashboard component

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-dashboard',
      templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
    })
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
       p:any
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access from the template, variables that aren't defined in the corresponding components.

In **header.component.html** you are setting `[ngModel]="searchText"` and variable **searchText** isn't defined on **header.component.ts**. Could it be **filterText** variable instead?

In **dashboard.component.html** you are setting `p = $event` and variable **p** isn't defined on **dashboard.component.ts**.  You also have an error about **newsService** being private. If you are gonna use it in the template it must be declared public when you inyect it on the constructor. I hope this helps. If you need more help is better if you provide a Stackblitz with minimum code.